# How to pass data and image both to "ASP.NET Core" Web API using Angular 2(typescript)?

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have code that can pass data only to web API but i want to pass data and Image both in **same request** not in different request using angular 2 + typescript and in ASP.Net Core Web API.

My Code to pass data to API:

Angular Code:

```
   create(user) {
    return this.authHttp.post(this._baseUrl + 'user/', JSON.stringify(userData)).map((res: Response) => {
        return res;
    }).catch(this.configService.handleError);
}
```

API Code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody]UserModel user)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        //save user
        _userRepository.Add(user);
        _userRepository.Commit();

        return new OkObjectResult(user.UserId);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

The simplest way is sending the image as a [base64 string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding).

Just create a simple JavaScript function to read the file and convert it to [base64 string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding). Do it before sending the file - probably [onchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536912(v=vs.85).aspx) event on the `<input>` will do the job for you.

Then you can store it directly in DB (or save as a file on the server if you need).

Image stored as base64 string can be send back and displaed directly by browser without additional actions, for example:

`<img src="data:image/bmp;base64,[base64EncodedImageHere]" />`

**Solution 2:**

*Frontend:*

If you are using HTML5 and a file upload control, just set form encoding as `multipart/form-data`:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

*Backend:*

Your property in the model should have type `IFormFile`, then you can save the file on the server:

```
IFormFile file;

using (var fileStream = File.Create( [file path here] ))
{
    await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    await fileStream.FlushAsync();
}
```

Comment: I'm using <input type="file"/> control. Please advise How can I bind that base 64 to <img>?

Comment: Use Angular/JacaScript - just create a simple function to read the file and convert it to base64 string. Do it before sending the file - probably `onchange` event on the `<input>` will do the job for you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536912(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: or you can use alternative way: `<form enctype='multipart/form-data'>` - I will update my answer.

Comment: @LukaszMakowej In case of solution 1, Consider there is a `Product` model which can have many `Images`, how can those models and their relations be realized? My original question here, I am trying to do exactly the same, it's just that for storing base64 `string` didn't work properly-it was chopping big string while saving so I read converting it to byte[] would solve the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43250261/asp-net-core-web-api-encode-string-to-base64

Comment: As always there is more than one way to do things ;) Array/List of strings works well in my case (I'm using AngularJS + WebAPI Core) - perhaps it depends on configuration or it's Encoding issue? I'm sending/storing strings and I'm not converting it to byte[] at any point so I'm not sure if it will work well.

Answer (score 0):

Just set your model and POST/PUT it via webapi as you are used to do.
I assume you have a web-api model object providing attributes for structured data and the image. usually a varbinary(max) in sql server.

In the snippet below I do what you are asking for with the "newattachment" object, which is actually a webapi-model.

For getting a new empty attachment-object I do a GET first against the webapi-Model used to store the images. In the next step I set the properties of this model including the image data itself ( a base64 encoded) string. Finally I do PUT/POST do save the object in the database)
**Client Side: Angular 2**

```
         this.dataService.getRecord('MT_DOKUMENTATION', -1)
            .subscribe((data: any[]) => {
                if (data) {
                var newattachment: any = data;
                newattachment.dokumentation = this.attachmentdata.split("base64,")[1];
                this.dataService.saveRecord('MT_DOKUMENTATION', "id", newattachment)
                    .subscribe((data: any[]) => {
                        var newrec: any = data;
                        ...
                    },
                    error => {
                        console.log(error);
                    },
                    () => {
                        console.log('Image Save complete')
                    });
                });
```

**Server Side (C#, Web API):**

```
        // PUT: api/MT_DOKUMENTATION/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutMT_DOKUMENTATION(int id, MT_DOKUMENTATION mT_DOKUMENTATION)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.Entry(mT_DOKUMENTATION).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
               ...              
            }

            return Ok(mT_DOKUMENTATION);
        }
```