# Difference between form data and base64 for sending image to .net API

Tags: angular, metadata, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on an angular 2 project and I want to send image with data to a .NET Core API. How can I achieve that?
I'm using a cropper that its output is base64.In other request I just send an image as formdata but now I have to send some images and a metadata.
I want to know what is difference between formdata and base64 sending.which one is better?

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass data and image both to "ASP.NET Core" Web API using Angular 2(typescript)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41425670/how-to-pass-data-and-image-both-to-asp-net-core-web-api-using-angular-2typesc)

Comment: when i send base64,API method parameter gets null then I replace file with this code 
{
 item.imageFile = result.croppedPicture.replace(/^data:image\/[a-z]+;base64,/, ""); 
}.
now my method get metadata with an image as byte array

Comment: Please update your question and add code what you have tried so far. If possible make a Plunker.

Answer (score 0):

Your server endpoint should look like this:

```
[HttpPost("upload")]
public void Upload(List<IFormFile> files, string example) {}
```

and your service function should look like this:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('files', file);
formData.append('example', 'extra');

return this.http.post(this.url + '/upload', formData);
```

the file is directly from an input type="file" (`inputEvent.target.files[0]`)